# What does the "!" operator do to the right of a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

e.g. `a += b! - c!;` I saw several expressions like this but I can't find what it's called or what it does

Comment: It’s the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Answer (score 5):

you're telling the compiler that even though judging purely by the code, the variable could be undefined, you, the programmer, know for 100% sure that it will have a value, so you're not going to do a check to see if it has a value or not.

See [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAKAbgQwE40wIwBsBTAfgC5EBnKXMAcwEpEBvAKDcUQHpvEAiLLgIl+iGFUSYkcAA6wEmQolk5MAW2JRi2ADTU4iKAAsJiCHBCEAJogCeMYjZXY4RYuqrlO5hFTgkAHSEcPQYOHjuwcQMJowA3BxcvIgA7sQA5NjERk6EMAxGxjkW6rIwJNhFmFBFOUKRJIjWxMAFMNqEdojGmJKYiFiEIMT6xOgxRZb0xuJQGf0y8vBgSipqmtrYPhZg-kEhYQ0ixACE0bHGCUniwIjhwu7M7FzJfGBwqXW+ZRU6iABrD6pSQmGqDCInRDqEA0HqYCZSCHDYg+Li7fbEYKhB6NLEkS7XLgAXw4pLYQA)